# Sonarqube ant IllegalStateException; not picking up properties file

Tags: ant, properties, sonarqube, illegalstateexception

I'm testing out Sonarqube 5.3 and the Sonarqube Ant 2.4 jar but am running into a problem when calling the ant sonar target in my build script

Here is my build script (C:\dev\poc\sonarpoc\sonarpoc.xml):

```
<project name="sonarpoc" basedir="." default="init" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">
    ...
    <target name="sonar">
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
            <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonarqube-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
            <classpath path="/dev/jars/opensource/sonarqube/2.4/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.jar" />
        </taskdef>
        <!-- Execute the SonarQube analysis -->
        <sonar:sonar />
    </target>
    ....
    <target name="build" depends="clean, compile, sonar, build-ear"/>
```

To execute from the command line I am calling:

```
C:\dev\poc\sonarpoc>ant -f sonarpoc.xml clean build
```

I have a sonar-project.properties defined in C:\dev\poc\sonarpoc which contains

```
# required metadata
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.projectKey=dev:sonarpoc
sonar.projectName=DEV-sonarpoc
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=source
```

So far, so good. I can run sonar-runner at this point and can see the analysis results at http://localhost:9000.

However, when I run the ant script as above, I'm getting this:

```
compile:

sonar:
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant version 1.7.1 compiled on June 27 2008
[sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.4
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/C:/dev/jars/opensource/sonarqube/2.4/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.jar
[sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\Users\john\.sonar\cache
[sonar:sonar] Load global repositories
[sonar:sonar] Load global repositories (done) | time=144ms
[sonar:sonar] User cache: C:\Users\john\.sonar\cache
[sonar:sonar] Load plugins index
[sonar:sonar] Load plugins index (done) | time=13ms
[sonar:sonar] Default locale: "en_IE", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
[sonar:sonar] Process project properties

BUILD FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:262)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:109)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:130)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.launchAnalysis(SonarQubeTask.java:72)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.ant.SonarQubeTask.execute(SonarQubeTask.java:55)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:758)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getCompoent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:60)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.checkMandatoryProperties(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:323)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.defineRootProject(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:179)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.execute(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:124)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.MutableProjectReactorProvider.provide(MutableProjectReactorProvider.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstanceCompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:60)
    ... 53 more

Total time: 5 seconds
C:\dev\poc\sonarpoc>
```

The

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
```

line from above is where the problem lies. It looks like the ant task can't recognize that there is a sonar-project.properties file in the current directory like sonar-runner can.

I'm thinking that there is additional path configuration needed to tell the ant task to look in the current directory for the sonar-project.properties file and to use it but I can't figure out what that is.

I tried adding:
    
to C:\dev\poc\sonarpoc\sonarpoc.xml but no joy.

EDIT:
The ant script with the build target runs successfully when I specify the sonar properties on the command line i.e.

```
C:\dev\poc\sonarpoc>ant -f sonarpoc.xml -Dsonar.projectKey=dev:sonarpoc -Dsonar.projectName=DEV-sonarpoc -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.sources=source clean build
```

so that reinforces my thoughts that there is some additional path configuration for the ant target to pickup the properties file is needed.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Why are you on 2.5? 5.3 is the latest.

Comment: Getting confused with sonar-runner version. Edited post for 5.3 of server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SonarQube Scanner for Ant does not support "sonar-project.properties" file out of the box. Is you take a look at the [documentation page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant), you'll see that you have to provide those properties inside the Ant file:

```
<!-- Define the SonarQube project properties -->
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:example-java-ant" />
<property name="sonar.projectName" value="Simple Java Project analyzed with the SonarQube Ant Task" />
<property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
<property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="build" />
<property name="sonar.java.libraries" value="lib/*.jar" />
```

If you still want to use a properties file to house those settings, I guess that you could invoke the [LoadProperties Ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) for that purpose. But I've never tried this so I can't guarantee this works.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you Fabrice.
I had tried using properties in the ant file before but the sonar.projectKey syntax was incorrect so was breaking on that. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

On SonarQube 5.1.2 I can to set property file for ant analysis with parameter `-propertyfile sonar-project.properties`.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple, Please verify that you are pointing to correct directory

Somtimes in cmd, it points to C:\

To move to another directory you need to add D:

So always verify in cmd, if you are pointing to the directory of right directory.